# I need help understanding this flowchart algorithm

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

[image]

From what I understand if N≠0, you will never get the output R since N div 5 will always be supperior to 0
Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: If at anytime during the iteration, the value of n<5, then the next time the loop condition will evaluate to false. Remember the integer division rule.

Answer (score 1):

`N := N div 5` will eventually reduce  N to 0; this is *integer* division.  For instance, here are the `R` and `N` values when `N` starts at 28:

```
r   n
3   5
30  1
301 0
```

Work through the algorithm with pencil and paper; do you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

it's like while N is different from 0 we affect the value R*10+ (N modulo 5) to R when we get out of the loop (N equals 0) we output R